# Android 4.4 Kitkat: Is there a way to run a service without android kill it after some time?

Tags: android, service, alarmmanager, android-4.4-kitkat, kill-process

I need a service that runs always in background without Android kills it after some time.

Before Android 4.4 Kitkat I used AlarmManager to do this, but now Android kills my services after some hours.

Is there a way to have services running in backgroud without Android 4.4 KitKat kill them?

Many thanks

Comment: You might want to describe what you are doing with the service such as is it holding a wakelock, how long should it run, what is the point of the AlarmManager.

Comment: There isn't anything in the documentation indicating that KitKat would kill your alarms after a while - however it clearly states that the alarms can be inaccurate because the system can chose to schedule the alarms at another time to minimize wakeups and battery use: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html - could this be the case for you?

Comment: I need a service with a broadcast receiver run by the action TIME_TICK because this action isn't recognized if I set it from manifest. @MorrisonChang or Darwind can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

Use START_STICKY to automatically run service once it is killed by android